# ¿Como hago para sumar el bucle, la condicion y los numeros que quedaron fuera del bucle en JS?

Tags: javascript

Necesito sumar los digitos de un array; para esto hice un loop que doblaba cada segundo digito y despues una condicional en la los numeros mayores a 9 se dividieran en digitos separados. Al final necesito sumar tanto los numeros ordinarios (los que no entraron en el loop), los numeros del loop que se doblaron pero son menores a 9, y los que se doblaron pero son mayores a 9.

Este es mi código hasta antes de la suma; en este caso mi variable "reversa" esta puesto como un ejemplo, ya que en el original se trata de un valor al azar que el usuario va a agregar

```js
let reversa = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
let sumaDigitos = 0
    for(let index = 1; index < reversa.length; index += 2) {
      let doblar = Number(reversa[index]) * 2;
      reversa[index] = doblar; 
        if (doblar > 9) {
          sumaDigitos = doblar.toString().split("").map(Number).reduce(function (a, b) { return a + parseInt(b)
          }, 0);
        console.log(sumaDigitos);
        
      }
 }
```

Comment: No entiendo mucho el objetivo ¿necesitas obtener el resultado de la suma de todos los números habidos en el array?

Comment: Si, para posteriormente hacer otros procedimientos, pero esa es la instruccion en la que no puedo avanzar

Comment: Sería un poco más fácil de entender lo que deseas hacer si pones un ejemplo del resultado deseado.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Si entendí bien lo que quieres hacer, tratas de sumar todos los dígitos de los números resultantes al multiplicar por 2 cada elemento del Array original.

Para tu ejemplo se tiene lo siguiente:

```js
const reversa = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const dobleReversa = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18];
const suma = 2 + 4 + 6 + 8 + (1 + 0) + (1 + 2) + ... + (1 + 8) // 45
```

Para lograrlo basta con realizar un par de mapeos y una reducción.

En el primer mapeo, vamos a "doblar" (multiplicar por 2 ) cada número del Array de entrada.

En el segundo mapeo, tomaremos cada valor del paso anterior y si el mismo es mayor que 9 (significa que tiene más de un dígito) lo separaremos en sus dígitos componentes para sumarlos y devolver la suma.

Finalmente, usamos una función reductora para sumar todos los valores y así devolver el resultado final.

Por ejemplo, la siguiente función hace todo eso sin modificar el Array original:

```js
const reversa = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
function sumaDoblada(numbersArray) {
  numbersArray = numbersArray
    .map(n => n*2)
    .map(n => {
      if(n < 10) {
        return n;
      }
      return n.toString().split('').map(c => Number(c)).reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0);
    });
  console.log(numbersArray.join(', '));
  return numbersArray.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0);;
}

console.log(reversa.join(', '));
console.log(sumaDoblada(reversa));
```

Para mostrar el Array resultante hice un `console.log` dentro de la función antes de hacer el `reduce`.

**Edición**

Gracias al [comentario de `infinit3loop`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/578874/como-hago-para-sumar-el-bucle-la-condicion-y-los-numeros-que-quedaron-fuera-de#comment1023322_578884) me he podido dar cuenta que deseas doblar los elementos de tu Array a razón de uno no y otro si. Pues para ello sólo hay que ajustar un poco el promer mapeo, de tal manera que sólo doble los elementos de los índices impares del Array.

Entonces tendríamos la siguiente salida:

```js
const reversa = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const dobleReversa = [1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 12, 7, 16, 9];
const suma = 1 + 4 + 3 + 8 + 5 + (1 + 2) + 7 + (1 + 9) + 9 // 47
```

Por ejemplo:

```js
const reversa = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
function sumaDoblada(numbersArray) {
  numbersArray = numbersArray
    .map((n, i) => (i % 2 ? n * 2 : n))
    .map(n => {
      if(n < 10) {
        return n;
      }
      return n.toString().split('').map(c => Number(c)).reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0);
    });
  console.log(numbersArray.join(', '));
  return numbersArray.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0);;
}

console.log(reversa.join(', '));
console.log(sumaDoblada(reversa));
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: No sé si entendí mal pero el creo que quiere doblar el array cada 2 elementos, no doblar el array entero